# Concrete5 admin site - no input file specified

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, concrete5

My working Conrete5 site recently developed a "no input file specified" problem on ALL admin pages. The root of the problem appears to be that admin pages have an unnecessary /index.php in the URL. I.E.

```
www.example.com/index.php/login/do_login......
```

If the /index.php part is removed from the URL the page will load (though all referenced files will still have /index.php hence fail to load).

I have concrete running in a sub directory but the page urls are from root e.g.

```
www.example.com/concrete-page-title...
```

This is the .htaccess file in my root directory relaying concrete requests to the concrete sub-directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
# redirect concrete
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/concrete
# permit normal access to wordpress installation
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ concrete/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have pretty urls turned on, here is the .htaccess file in my concrete sub-directory (/concrete).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Sidenote:
`cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` (have changed to 0, no change)

And the site is not hosted with GoDaddy.

The sites been for a fair while now with no updates, despite my fiddling I have had no success so any suggestions greatly welcome.

Comment: have you checked out Jordan Lev's comments here: http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/chat/no-input-file-specified1/

Comment: Sadly yes, I've tried all of those rules a few times over :(

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked on a site where the server's PHP had been upgraded:

in config/site.php add:

```
define('SERVER_PATH_VARIABLE', 'REQUEST_URI');
define('DIR_REL', '');
```

Comment: Have tried the Request URI approach. As a result of my directory setup I have define('DIR_REL', ''); and define('DIR_REL2', '/concrete'); DIR_REL2 is only used in libraries/request.php in accordance with this http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/hide-the-subdirectory-url/